# Как сделать так что бы строка json для парсинга бралась с url и при этом читалась потоково, а не бралась полностью вся?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, потоки-данных, gson

Добрый день, нужно обработать потоково(streaming) строку json через библиотеку gson. Если строку задаю вручную, то обрабатывается нормально. Как сделать так что бы строка бралась с url и при этом читалась тоже потоково, а не бралась полностью вся?
[image: exmpl]

Comment: Bufferreader пробовли?

Comment: нет, не пробывал

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сделать свой `InputStreamReader`:

```
public class MyISReader extends InputStreamReader {

    private int readBytes = 0;

    public MyISReader(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        readBytes += length;
        return super.read(cbuf, offset, length);
    }

    public int getReadBytes() {
        return readBytes;
    }

    public void flushReadBytes() {
        readBytes = 0;
    }
}
```

В конструктор нужно передать `InputStream` с потоком byte, получаемых по сети.
Затем создать новый `JsonReader`

```
InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(body.byteStream(), 1024 * 8);
MyISReader myISReader = new MyISReader(bis);
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(myISReader);
```

Comment: спасибо!
Если я сейчас создам класс  MyISReader, а затем вставлю код который ниже в Мейн то выйдет все, без каких либо изменений с моей стороны?

Comment: Вы еще с сети должны InputStream пробрасывать. Если делать как обычный запрос то он вам весь json скачает

Comment: (body.byteStream(), 1024 * 8);
body cannot resolve symbol...

Comment: `readBytes += length;` делать нельзя. `read` не обязательно вернёт такое же количество данных.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего создавать своего не нужно: всё, что нужно для такой задачи, можно получить прямо средствами самой Java (да и Android):

```java
public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    final URL url = new URL(...);
    try ( final InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
          final BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
          final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(bufferedInputStream);
          final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(reader) ) {
        while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Код не совсем в "стиле" Android, но здесь этого и не нужно. `inputStream` берётся откуда угодно (в данном случае -- `URL` присутствует исключительно в целях демонстрации). Дальше, хорошей практикой считается буферизированное чтение потока байтов. После того, как есть какой-угодно инстанс `InputStream`, последний нужно завернуть в `Reader`. Почему? Потому что `Reader` в отличие от `InputStream` оперирует символьными данными (а не занимается побайтовой обработкой). Эта особенность исключительно важна, как и для хорошего программирования вообще (не весь мир в ASCII, конечно же), так и для Gson. В случае с Gson объект класса `Reader` нужно передать в `JsonReader`, которому далеко всё-равно откуда производится чтение контента. И да, такой подход позволяет читать сколь угодно длинные потоки данных в один запрос.